# The smallest index i of the list such that the prefix sum of array elements from 0 to i is less then some constant c in F#

Tags: lambda, f#, functional-programming

Assuming list consists of positive numbers.

I can make a partial sum, zip it with the {0..n} and run something on this, but it feels clumsy and non-lazily evaluated.

Recursive lambda would probably work better, but I not sure if recursive lambdas are possible and I feel like there must be very clean solution for this.

Example:

```
list [2;2;3;4;5]
c = 5
partial sums [2;4;7;11;16] => return 1(because a[1] = 4 <= c < a[2] = 7)
```

Comment: you have tried to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: yes, I made solutions with recursive function(paragraph 3) and thought about partial sum and zipping it with range(parapraph 2), but was unable to google a best and clean way do to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like `scanl` and `takeWhile` in haskell. Then you could do something like:

```
let sums = takeWhile (<c) (scanl (+) 0 original)
in length sums - 1
```

Comment: awesome, there is takeWhile in f# as well. Thanks! Will wait a little longer and accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Seq.findIndex` and keep a running total, like so:

```
let smallestIndexWhileSumIsUnder maxSum seq =
    let sum = ref 0
    let indexWhereSumIsTooMuch =
        seq
        |> Seq.findIndex (fun i ->
            sum := !sum + i
            !sum >= maxSum
        )
    indexWhereSumIsTooMuch - 1
```

Usage:

```
smallestIndexWhileSumIsUnder 10 [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6]
```

Result:

```
2
```

---

Alternatively, if what you want is the sequence itself, you can use `Seq.takeWhile` and do it like this:

```
let takeWhileSumIsUnder maxSum seq =
    let sum = ref 0
    seq
    |> Seq.takeWhile (fun i ->
        sum := !sum + i
        !sum < maxSum
    )
```

Usage:

```
takeWhileSumIsUnder 10 [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6]
```

Result:

```
seq [1; 2; 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

The smallest index is `i = 0`. Unless you mean the largest `i`, then here's a recursive algorithm that uses pattern matching. Note that I don't allow the index to be lower than 0:

```
let rec smallestIndexRecursive sumTotal currIndex maxSum list =
    match list with
    | [] -> currIndex
    | head::tail -> match head with
                    | head when (head + sumTotal) < maxSum -> 
                    smallestIndexRecursive  (head + sumTotal) (currIndex + 1) maxSum tail
                    | _ when currIndex <= 0 -> 0
                    | _ -> currIndex - 1

smallestIndexRecursive 0 0 maxSum list
```

Timing it vs the solution posted by Roujo with the following:

```
open System.Diagnostics

let n = 8000
let maxSum = 10000 

let random = System.Random 543252

let randomlists = 
  [for i in [1..n] -> [ for i in [1..n] -> random.Next (0, 10)]]


let stopWatch = 
  let sw = Stopwatch ()
  sw.Start ()
  sw


let timeIt (name : string) (a : int list -> 'T) : unit = 
  let t = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds
  let v = a (randomlists.[0]) 
  randomlists |> List.tail 
              |> List.map (fun list -> a list) 
              |> ignore
  let d = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds - t
  printfn "%s, elapsed %d ms, result %A" name d v



let alg1 list = 
    let smallestIndexRef maxSum list =
        let sum = ref 0
        let indexWhereSumIsTooMuch =
            list
            |> List.findIndex (fun i ->
                sum := !sum + i
                !sum >= maxSum
            )
        indexWhereSumIsTooMuch - 1
    smallestIndexRef maxSum list

let alg2 list = 
    let rec smallestIndexRecursive sumTotal currIndex maxSum list =
        match list with
        | [] -> currIndex
        | head::tail -> match head with
                        | head when (head + sumTotal) < maxSum -> 
                        smallestIndexRecursive  (head + sumTotal) (currIndex + 1) maxSum tail
                        | _ when currIndex <= 0 -> 0
                        | _ -> currIndex - 1
    smallestIndexRecursive 0 0 maxSum list

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =  
    timeIt "findIndex" alg1 
    timeIt "Recursive" alg2
    0
```

The result I get on my computer is:

```
findIndex, elapsed 76 ms, result 2220
Recursive, elapsed 49 ms, result 2220
```